# efficient way to convert list of points to table

Tags: python, data-structures

I have a list in memory/in a csv file of points...

```
x1,y1,z1
x1,y2,z2
...
x4,y38,z
...
xn,yn,zn
```

Is there an efficiënt way to convert this dataset to a 2d table in another csv file with the x-values in the first row and the y values in the first column and the z value on the corresponding place?

It's possible with for/while loops, but maybe there's a better way to address this problem?

Comment: Do you have it in memory or a csv file?

Comment: pandas `pivot_table()`?

Comment: It's in memory and I wrote the list of points to a CSV file, but i also want a CSV file with a 'table' representation